# Why does ghci doesn't recognise inits function

Tags: haskell

Im using ghci and when i try to use "inits" function I get error:

```
Not in scope: `inits'
    Perhaps you meant `init' (imported from Prelude)
```

But this function should be predefinied according to this: 
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import `Data.List`:

```
:m +Data.List
inits [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

alternatively you could use the full name

```
Data.List.inits [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Comment: You can add `Data.List` to your ghci.conf if you use functions from it frequent enough to avoid importing `Data.List` each time you open ghci.